# Iterating over fields of a layer in Scapy

Tags: python, iteration, packet, scapy

I want to iterate over the names of the fields such as `src` and `dst` and also have their values., I tried this:

```
for field in pkt['Ethernet']:
    print field
```

But I need a function that will give me a dictionary with the name of the field and his value, for example -

```
{'dst':'00:0a:95:9d:68:16','src':'00:0a:95:9d:68:16','type':'tcp'}
```

Comment: Can you give an example output of what you would expect?

Comment: What are you getting/expecting?

Comment: I want to show all the fields of the packed that are sniffed in a gui application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, get all the field names from the protocol type, then use `getattr` to get the value from the packet / frame:

```
field_names = [field.name for field in Ether.fields_desc]
fields = {field_name: getattr(frame, field_name) for field_name in field_names}
```

`fields` will then be equal:

```
{'dst': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'src': '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'type': 36864}
```